# Does Google support Article Rich Snippets?

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have been looking at [rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic) in google. Google lists the following [schema.org](http://www.schema.org) items as being supported:

- Reviews
- People
- List item
- Products
- Businesses and organizations
- Recipes
- Events Music

I have noticed that in search results, Google displays Rich Snippets for Article and BlogPosting. When clicking on the link and using Firebug to check the source code, I can see that the schema.org being used is indeed BlogPosting.

I've tried adding BlogPosting to my sample code and using [Google's Rich Snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=) to check the results but I cant get an image to display. I am using the following code:

```html
<html>
<body> etc etc....

<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
     <img itemprop="image" href="/images/test.jpg" item>
</div>

...
```

Although it doesn't show the image in the Rich Snippet tool, it does recognize that an image has been set and displays the url text in the "Extracted rich snippet data from the page" box. I have tried using the SoftwareApplication schema and then I get an image to show.

My question is: Does the Rich Snippet tool restrict the images it shows based on the schemas listed above, and actually once in the live search results, Rich Snippets for Article and BlogPostings will be shown?

Answer (score 1):

Google has introduced Rich Snippet for Articles, so you can now use articles snippet for your article/blog post.

See this official document from Google on implementing rich snippet for your articles: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

And as far as your image issue is concerned, try to apply the snippet code as per the document above and it should show the image. I tested it and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Google is not going to display product images in SERPS for schema.org/Article or schema.org/BlogPosting item types. It's going to show the Author profile image that it pulls from Google+ using one of two methods:

https://plus.google.com/authorship

... think about it. Everyone would be trying to attach add some (spammy) image next to their blog post in SERPS. Google only wants to show verified authorship by their authentification methods (via G+) -- not just from any "author" tag in microdata.

Yes, the rich snippet tool will not show you what the actual SERP will always look like, because it depends on the query. In fact they say

> Note that there is no guarantee that a Rich Snippet will be shown for
>   this page on actual search results.

Comment: I dont agree with 'Everyone would be trying to attach add some (spammy) image next to their blog post in SERPS.' because 'Note that there is no guarantee that a Rich Snippet will be shown for this page on actual search results.' Do some google searches (news articles are the prime example). They contain images that aren't authors